How can I remove the lower sash in this window?
I recently bought my first house and can’t figure out for the life of me how to remove this lower sash. I watched a few videos and none of them particularly matched up with my type of window. I apologize in advance for the paint over the track, the person that sold me the house did the "landlord special" to the entire place lol.




FYI: Not all are removable without partially disassembling the window frame.

@Ecnerwal like taking the trim off?

Whatever part of it is holding the sash (or the track it runs in) in place, whcih looks like the wall trim and then the next piece here; sometimes there's a piece that can be pried off the side without disturbing the wall trim, does not look likely here. But wait and see if someone else knows a trick applicable to this specific type. Perhaps something can be slid up the track to depress a spring loaded pin or something like that. All-wood ones are almost always take it apart. Metal track improves the odds that there might be an easier way.

A picture, close to one side and straight down from above the lower sash may help.

If the "glides" or ballasts on either side are vinyl, some sash lift out by raising the lower sash a few inches, and tilting the top of the winds towards you letting it pivot at the bottom. Bring it all the way down 90 degree!! This is imperative. Doing this will allow the glides to lock in at the location the window is in, so one side of the widow can be lifted off the glide on one side so the sash can be lifted out at an angle.
Reassembly is the reverse

Note "some", though. Don't force anything; if moderate force doesn't work, truly something else.

That is correct

I've seen a version where one sash had catches at the top that released the top to swing down and  inward, while the other sash sorta "unsnapped" at the bottom under moderate pressure (when not locked!) and pivoted upward and inward. After pivoting this way, a slight clockwise or counterclockwise twist created space to release the pivot pins from their slides in the frame and dismount the entire sash. Point is that there are a number of different systems and you have to either find someone who knows yours or look at online documentation and (gently) experiment

s/truly/try/ above. Darned autodefect...

I was going to say, add that as an answer.

Probably should. Don't want to try doing that edit on this phone, at least not right now.
